# php - uniformize date strings with different formats

Tags: php, date

I have an array with many different formats of dates. All strings.

I want to uniformize this into an array with dates(). Something like this:

```
function uniformize($str){
  $date = strtotime($str);
  return $date;
}

$arr = array(
  '07/29/1975',
  '20/01/1981',
  '1983-05-24',
  '10 /8 /1995'
  );

print_r( array_map('uniformize', $arr) );
```

But this only works with one format:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 
  [1] => 
  [2] => 454215600 
  [3] => 
)
```

Is there any way I can do it for all formats?

Comment: If you do not *know* what format your dates are in, there's little PHP can do for you. Seriously, the first step would be to ensure that you define and know what format your dates are in. Otherwise *you* will have to write a bunch of heuristics to deal with this problem.

Comment: Could u provide what kind of dates will have to be formatted - So i could help u with str_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function for that. Fiddle [here](http://viper-7.com/7XqwcX)

Notice it's supposed to have always the days before than the months. Otherwise it's impossible to know whether first part of the date is a day or a month (unless the day is more than 12.. and can't cover all the cases).

```
function date2time($date)
 {
    $date = str_replace(' ','',$date);
    if(strpos($date,'-')!==false)
      $date_array = explode('-',$date);
    if(strpos($date,'/')!==false)
     $date_array = explode('/',$date);
    //add more delimiters if needed

    $day = $month = $year = '';

   foreach($date_array as $date_elem)
   {
    if(strlen($date_elem) < 3)
    {
       if(empty($day))
         $day = $date_elem;
       else
         $month = $date_elem;

    }else
      $year = $date_elem;
   }


    $time = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);

    return $time;
  }

$arr = array(
  '07/29/1975',
  '20/01/1981',
  '1983-05-24',
  '10 /8 /1995'
  );

print_r( array_map('date2time', $arr) );
```

Comment: [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) uses its entire first argument as delimiter. You need to use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to be able to split the string using only one of  '-', '/', '.' as delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think you have to detect yourself the format and then convert it into the format you wish...
The real problem is about months and days... 
some use `31-12-2014`, other countries use `12-31-2014`...
so you HAVE to define which is the month and the day in a string like `05-06-2015`...

**EDIT :**

You have many regex to do...
I'm using this for 2015-12-31 format :

```
if(preg_match("/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/", $yourDate, $split)) && (checkdate($split[2],$split[3],$split[1]))) {
    // do stuff where $split[1] is years, split[2] is month, and split[3] is day
}
```

Then you may adapt it to every formats you encounter changing order...
`checkdate` checks if it is a valide date (2015-52-38 is not a valid date)
You may also find some on google with "date pattern regex" for instance...

Comment: example on how to detect format? maybe using regex?

Answer (score 1):

The first two strings use `/` as component separator. The function [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) consider them to be formatted according to the [American format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php): `month/day/year`. Because `24` and `20` are invalid month numbers they cannot be parsed correctly.

The last string (`'10 /8 /1995'`) looks like a short date format but the spaces inside the components also render it invalid.

As it is explained in a note in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) of function `strtotime()`:

> **Note:**
> Dates in the `m/d/y` or `d-m-y` formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (`/`), then the American `m/d/y` is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (`-`) or a dot (`.`), then the European `d-m-y` format is assumed.

#### What can you do

If you know the order of components in your dates you can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to always use `/` for `m/d/y` (the American format) and `-` for `d-m-y` (the European format). Also, you should strip the spaces.

Another option is to write your own date parser to identify the date components then use [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) or [`DateTime::setDate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php) to get the date. However, if the date have both the day and the month in `1..12`, the format cannot be detected and it have to be assumed (from the separator).